# Remove the Leading WhiteSpaces from all XML Files in a Folder

Tags: xml, vbscript

I want to trim all the leading spaces from the XML files in the folder.
I have this script but this does the file name with spaces are trim.

```vb
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolderName = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
  objFSO.MoveFile strFolderName + "\" + objFile.Name , strFolderName + "\" + 
    Replace(objFile.Name," ", "")
Next
```

I want to trim the space inside the file.

```xml
<test>
<item/>
<item/>
<item/>
</test>
```

Comment: What about `<item>This is a test item</item>`? What happens with that? Why are you trying to do this with VBScript instead of a proper DOM parser?

Comment: Is powershell an option?  https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+readalltext

Comment: *I want to trim the space inside the file.* No, you don't. Trust me. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why do you think you need to remove the indention from the XML files?